# Why the door/s colors flag is all the time true/false and all the time change between true and false?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This script is attached to a door :

Even if the variable doorLockState is set to true enabled true in the editor and the door should be color in red the door is green using a breakpoint the state variable inside ColorDoors is change between red and green non stop once state is true next it's false but in the editor it's all the time checked as true :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System;

[ExecuteAlways]
public class HoriDoorManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<DoorHori> doors = new List<DoorHori>();
    public bool doorLockState;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (transform.parent != null)
        {
            Transform parent = transform.parent;
            var children = parent.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

            if (children != null)
            {
                foreach (Transform door in children)
                {
                    if (door.name == "Door_Left" || door.name == "Door_Right")
                        doors.Add(door.GetComponent<DoorHori>());
                }
            }
            ColorDoors(Color.red, Color.green, doorLockState);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        if (doorLockState == false)
        {
            if (doors != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < doors.Count; i++)
                {
                    doors[i].OpenDoor();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        ColorDoors(Color.red, Color.green, doorLockState);
    }

    private void ColorDoors(Color red, Color green, bool state)
    {
        List<Transform> children = new List<Transform>();

        for (int i = 0; i < doors.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach (Transform child in doors[i].GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
            {
                if (child == doors[i].transform)
                    continue;

                var renderer = child.GetComponent<Renderer>();
                renderer.sharedMaterial.shader = Shader.Find("Unlit/ShieldFX");

                if (state == true)
                {
                    renderer.sharedMaterial.SetColor("_MainColor", red);
                    LockState(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    renderer.sharedMaterial.SetColor("_MainColor", green);
                    LockState(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public bool GetLockState
    {
        get { return doorLockState; }
        set { doorLockState = value; }
    }

    private void LockState(bool state)
    {
        var collider = gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>();

        if (state == false)
        {
            collider.size = new Vector3(2.3f, 2.736307f, 2.5f);
            collider.center = new Vector3(0, 1.378154f, 0);
            collider.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(-1.57f, 0, -2.98f);
            collider.isTrigger = true;
        }
        else
        {
            collider.size = new Vector3(2.3f, 2.736307f, 3);
            collider.center = new Vector3(0, 1.378154f, 0);
            collider.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(-1.57f, 0, -2.98f);
            collider.isTrigger = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot of a door constructor in the Hierarchy and the script in the Inspector:

[image: Door Constructor]

The object Horizontal_Doors_Kit tag is set to Door.

And this is the editor script that should let me control the doors but there is also a problem here too since in the editor it's not listing all the doors :

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(DoorsLockManager))]
public class DoorsLockManagerEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty _doors;
    private SerializedProperty _globalLockState;

    private bool shouldOverwrite;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _doors = serializedObject.FindProperty("Doors");
        _globalLockState = serializedObject.FindProperty("_globalLockState");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        serializedObject.Update();

        shouldOverwrite = false;

        // Begin a change check here
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(_globalLockState);
        if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
        {
            // overwrite only once if changed
            shouldOverwrite = true;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < _doors.arraySize; i++)
        {
            var door = _doors.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);

            // if door == null the script itself has an error since it can't even find the SerializedProperty
            if (door == null)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("There was an error in the editor script!\nPlease check the log", MessageType.Error);
                Debug.LogError("Couldn't get door property", target);
                return;
            }

            if (door.objectReferenceValue == null) continue;

            var serializedDoor = new SerializedObject(door.objectReferenceValue);

            var lockState = serializedDoor.FindProperty("doorLockState");

            serializedDoor.Update();

            if (lockState == null)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("There was an error in the editor script!\nPlease check the log", MessageType.Error);
                Debug.LogError("Couldn't get lockState property", target);
                return;
            }

            // HERE OVERWRITE
            if (shouldOverwrite)
            {
                lockState.boolValue = _globalLockState.boolValue;
            }
            else
            {
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(lockState, new GUIContent("Door " + i + " Lockstate"));
            }

            serializedDoor.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

Screenshot of the editor script inspector :

[image: Doors Editor]

It's showing the two variables Global Lock State but it should also list the 12 doors.

- The first problem the state of the door/s is all the time unlocked green color.
- The second problem is why it's not listing all the doors so I can control each/all the doors either in editor or runtime ?

And the script DoorsLockManager :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class DoorsLockManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public List<HoriDoorManager> Doors = new List<HoriDoorManager>();

    // The global state
    [SerializeField] private bool _globalLockState;

    // During runtime use a property instead
    public bool GlobalLockState
    {
        get { return _globalLockState; }
        set
        {
            _globalLockState = value;

            // apply it to all doors
            foreach (var door in Doors)
            {
                // now you would need it public again
                // or use the public property you had there
                door.doorLockState = _globalLockState;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        var doors = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Door");
        Doors = new HoriDoorManager[doors.Length].ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < doors.Length; i++)
        {
            Doors[i] = doors[i].GetComponent<HoriDoorManager>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are getting two Global Lock State tick boxes because you are calling base.OnInspectorGUI() and then drawing another tick box with EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(_globalLockState) in the DoorsLockManagerEditor class.

However, without knowing the contents of the DoorsLockManager class it isn't possible to answer this completely; the bool doorLockState in the HoriDoorManager class is never set by the code provided for instance.

Comment: @Pikanchion You right I forgot to add it so edited my question and added now the DoorsLockManager script too,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your `Doors` list is only being updated when `Awake()` is called in your `DoorsLockManager` (and not accessible from the inspector), which means the list is always empty outside of runtime. Changing this should allow the list to be displayed in the inspector while editing.

Making the following minor changes to **DoorsLockManager.cs**:

```
private void Awake()
{
    UpdateDoors();
}

public void UpdateDoors()
{
    var doors = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Door");
    Doors = new HoriDoorManager[doors.Length].ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < doors.Length; i++)
    {
        Doors[i] = doors[i].GetComponent<HoriDoorManager>();
    }
}
```

and adding the following to the top of the `OnInspectorGUI()` method in **DoorsLockManagerEditor.cs**:

```
if (GUILayout.Button("Update Door List"))
{
    ((DoorsLockManager)target).UpdateDoors();
}
```

should achieve this by providing a button to update the list when needed.

Individual and global lock states should now be functional, however only one of the two `Global Lock State` toggles is properly functional, this can be fixed by either removing `base.OnInspectorGUI();` from the `OnInspectorGUI()` method in **DoorsLockManagerEditor.cs** or by adding `[HideInInspector]` before `[SerializeField] private bool _globalLockState;` in **DoorsLockManager.cs**.

Currently **HoriDoorManager.cs** will only update their respective doors at runtime as the `ColorDoors` method is called only in `Awake()` and `Update()`. This can instead be made to update whenever the `doorLockState` bool is changed by modifying your `GetLockState` property as so:

```
public bool GetLockState
{
    get { return doorLockState; }
    set
    {
        doorLockState = value;
        ColorDoors(Color.red, Color.green, doorLockState);
    }
}
```

and assigning to this property instead of the backing variable in the `GlobalLockState` property of **DoorsLockManager.cs** (replacing line 28: `door.doorLockState = _globalLockState;` with `door.GetLockState = _globalLockState;`).

---

Edit:
This is a bit of a quick hack but adding the following to **DoorsLockManager.cs**:

```cs
public void UpdateColors()
{
    foreach (var door in Doors)
    {
        door.GetLockState = door.GetLockState;
    }
}
```

and the following to `OnInspectorGUI()` in **DoorsLockManagerEditor.cs** beneath the other button:

```
    if (GUILayout.Button("Update Door Colors"))
    {
        ((DoorsLockManager)target).UpdateColors();
    }
```

should allow you to tell the doors to update their colours from the inspector manually.

Comment: Still not working. It does showing the door/s in the editor now but it's not changing the doors color from green to red.  Here is a link for a rar file contains my scripts also a door prefab. Maybe you can check it ? https://filebin.net/lq5c371593ajea3e

Comment: I think the problem is in the script HoriDoorManager the method ColorDoors is never called in the editor mode if it's inside Start or Awake but only in the Update and in the Update it's changing all the time the lockstate of the doors and keep them unlocked.  I tried to add [ExecuteInEditMode] or [ExecuteAlways] but it's keep calling the ColorDoors method nonstop in the Update never call it in the Awake or Start, So it's messed up.

Comment: @DanielLip this edit should work, you could certainly call the ColorDoors method more elegantly than I have here but it would likely require me refactoring a lot of the other code.